# How do you message a friend on Clash Of Clans, without being in the clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is there a way to message a friend that is in my recent clan that I was recently in?

Answer (score 2):

Clash of Clans does not have a built-in private message function, likely for privacy reasons, but you can still message your friend with some workarounds listed below.

If you don't care about people in public seeing your message, use the public chat (but your friend has to be online at the same time for this to work).

If you do care about people in public seeing your message, there are multiple ways to get around the lack of friend direct messaging, which includes

- Joining the clan that you were recently in if there's a spot available
- Try to make your friend join the clan that you're currently in (somehow)
- Connecting with them through social media, Discord, or phone number, etc.
- Some other way to private message them not listed above

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to message a friend without being in the same clan. If you want to message them, you should text them or talk to them on Discord.

Answer (score -1):

You have to be friends with them on Facebook, then you can message them. I believe that's the only way so far. Correct me if I'm wrong, I deleted the app several months ago.